# How to set tool tip value to larger text

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, tooltip

I have a DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl on my winform and inside that I have added one DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn control to show some values from DB. Since the value coming from DB is very long and grid size is small I wanted to display full value in tooltip. but it seems it is picking up only first few chars(may be 256). How I can display complete value in tooltip.

That would be great, if anyone can tell me defualt size of tooltip for DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.

Comment: What if the tooltip had 2000 characters? Or 10000? Would you want that to hide half your screen, or all of it, with an annoying hover? Or rather some alternative show-more capability?

Comment: yes... I think you are right... I'll add new show-more functionality. btw... That would be great, if anyone can tell me defualt size of tooltip for DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a SuperToolTip. So you have to place in your form a DX Tooltip controller. Configure "ToolTipType" property to "ToolTipType.SuperTip"

Then assign it to the Grid vía "ToolTipController" property.

Now, add an event handler to GetActiveObjectInfo event from the Tooltipcontroller.

Now, assing tooltip text dinamically so (as I used it from VB.net, I will pasted you some example C# code from DX examples)

void GetActiveObjectInfo:

```
if(e.SelectedControl == gridControl1) {
   GridView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as GridView;
   GridHitInfo info = view.CalcHitInfo(e.ControlMousePosition);
   if(info.InRowCell) {
      string text = "Text - " +     view.GetRowCellDisplayText(info.RowHandle, info.Column);
      string cellKey = info.RowHandle.ToString() + " - " + info.Column.ToString();
      e.Info = new DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControlInfo(cellKey, text);
     // this area it's where you have to put your full text
   }
}
```